# Duplicate Off-Topic Reasons

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, flag-dialog

I just flagged a post here on meta as off-topic and saw that there are two quite similar reasons for closing something that shouldn't be here.

> This question does not appear to be about Stack Overflow or the
>   software that powers the Stack Exchange network, within the scope
>   defined in the help center.

and

> Blatantly off-topic (this question has nothing to do with Stack
>   Overflow or the software that powers the Stack Exchange network)

[image: Off-Topic Reasons]

I'm not a native english speaker, but to me it sounds that the second one is more off-topic than the first one.

But that wouldn't make sense, either it is off-topic or its not, why would there two reasons?

Comment: I think when you get to 3k rep, the second one becomes "because..." and you enter a comment explaining why.

Comment: @TZHX So it does, I never noticed ;)

Comment: You forgot to notice the fact that there are two places to mark something as a duplicate. `:P`

Comment: Given the 100+ Stack Exchange sites, it's hard to judge whether it's "blatantly off-topic".

Answer (score 28, accepted):

For users having <3000 reps, [Blatantly off-topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185873/) is available as a flagging option across all SE sites.

Though both the OT options look similar but it is not a bug as per [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185867/no-custom-off-topic-message-when-flagging-on-so/185873#comment768551_185873):

> we're just emphasizing it a bit for flaggers - Shog9♦